# Mongoose static variables/Global non volatile variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, mongoose-schema

I am writing code in Nodejs & need to implement a global queueCount for documents of a 'Processes' schema, is there some way to store static variables on schema level(like methods) that can be accessed commonly by all documents made form model of that schema, Also I need to modify the queueCount.
If there is another better option without diving into schema that'll also work please suggest that aswell(basically need a global variable, that's not volatile(resets incase server restarts or crashes) and preferably stored on db instead of server instance)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const constants = require('../constant/constant');

const QueueProcessSchema = new Schema({
    projectId: {
        required: true,
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Project'
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: constants.processStatus
    },
    version: {
        type: String
    },
    isPublic: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },
    queueRank: {
        type: Number,
        default: -1
    }
});

QueueProcessSchema.plugin(require('mongoose-timestamp'));
QueueProcessSchema.plugin(require('mongoose-delete'), {
    overrideMethods: true,
    deletedAt: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Schema.prototype.method()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#Schema.prototype.method()) may be of use to you. It allows you to add custom methods to your shemas and in your case could be used to return an arbitrary value. For example:

```js
QueueProcessSchema.method('Everest', function () {
  return 8848.86;
});

const queueProcess = mongoose.model('QueueProcess', QueueProcessSchema);

const doc = new queueProcess;
doc.Everest();
// 8848.86
```